# how to add objects to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to construct an array of objects from a set of two different arrays. I'm a little comfussed on where I need to go from here.

I'm creating a unique key value, but the object is going into the array individual.

```
const startingArray = [
{
 key: "description",
 value: "my description"
},
{
 key: "description2",
 value: "my description2"
},
{
 key: "description3",
 value: "my description3"
},
]
```

my logic

```
const k = mystartingArray.reduce((acc, d, count) => {
 const name = Object.value(d)[0]
 const title = Object.value(d)[1]

const value = {
 [name]: title
}
acc.push(value)

return acc

},[])
```

how I want the Array to look

```
const finishedArray = [
{
   description: "my description",
   description2: "my description2,
   description3: "my description3,
}
```

How far am I off?

Comment: The finishedArray is an array with one element that is an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be simpler to solve just by using a basic `forEach`.

```
let value = {};

startingArray.forEach(obj => {
    value[obj.key] = obj.value;
});

const finishedArray = [value];
```

---

Or, if you don't want to have a `value` object:

```
const finishedArray = [{}];

startingArray.forEach(obj => {
  finishedArray[0][obj.key] = obj.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const finishedArray = [
  startingArray.reduce((a, v) => {a[v.key] = v.value; return a}, {})
]
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, if I wanted to also have them separate into there own objects like [{description:description},{description2:description2},{description3:description3}]

Comment: Use map instead of reduce.

Comment: How would go about using map

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: so using map after I've done the array? I thought before

Answer (score 1):

To finish your code:

```js
const startingArray = [
  {
    key: "description",
    value: "my description"
  },
  {
    key: "description2",
    value: "my description2"
  },
  {
    key: "description3",
    value: "my description3"
  },
];

const k = startingArray.reduce((acc, d, count) => {
  return [{
    ...(acc[0] || {}),
    [d.key]: d.value
  }]
},[])

console.log(k);
```

However, I think the solution of Rocket Hazmat is more reasonable than this.